# Setting the Record Source of a subform in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Dim newRS
newRS = "SELECT DISTINCT [Grp_ID], [Group_Name], [Group_NPI] FROM [GROUP]"
Forms!loclistingfrm!LocationListSubFrm.RecordSource = newRS
```

When I look at the LocationListSubFrm sub form in Design View, there is no Record Source property. However, when I access it directly from the objects pane I can see it.

Is the fact that it's a subform preventing me from changing the record source? The same subform is recycled throughout my application, so I can't really edit it at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do note, that you need to address the subform *control*, not the (sub)form itself:

```
Dim newRS As String

newRS = "SELECT DISTINCT [Grp_ID], [Group_Name], [Group_NPI] FROM [GROUP]"
Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.RecordSource = newRS
```

Comment: So if I have say, seven different controls, I would need to rewrite this line for each individual control?

Comment: That depends, but it sounded as what you intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding .form.recordsource as shown below.

```
Dim newRS
    newRS = "SELECT DISTINCT [Grp_ID], [Group_Name], [Group_NPI] FROM [GROUP]"
    Forms!loclistingfrm!LocationListSubFrm.form.RecordSource = newRS
```